# Change y axis range of a secondary axis in python Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two plots overlaid on each other generated by the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

width=.5
t=pd.DataFrame({'bars':[3.4,3.1,5.1,5.1,3.8,4.2,5.2,4.0,3.6],'lines':[2.4,2.2,2.4,2.1,2.0,2.1,1.9,1.8,1.9]})
t['bars'].plot(kind='bar',width=width)
t['lines'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='red')

ax=plt.gca()
plt.xlim([-width,len(t['bars'])-width])
ax.set_xticklabels(('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
plt.show()
```

[image: pic]

I want to be able to scale the range of the second y axis to go from 0.0 to 2.5 (instead of 1.8 to 2.4) in steps of .5. How can I define this without changing the bar chart at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas returns the axis on which it plots when you call the plot function. Just save that axis and modify the limits using the object oriented approach.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

width=.5

t=pd.DataFrame({'bars':[3.4,3.1,5.1,5.1,3.8,4.2,5.2,4.0,3.6],'lines':[2.4,2.2,2.4,2.1,2.0,2.1,1.9,1.8,1.9]})
ax1 = t['bars'].plot(kind='bar',width=width)
ax2 = t['lines'].plot(secondary_y=True, color='red')

ax2.set_ylim(0, 2.5)

ax1.set_xlim([-width,len(t['bars'])-width])
ax1.set_xticklabels(('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
plt.show()
```